# Add JSON file to JS with the PHP include function

Tags: javascript, php, json, hosting

I used to do the following to add the content of a JSON file to my JS code, but since I changed my web host I get this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

```
var someVar = <?php include 'someJsonFile.geojson'; ?>;
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You probably had your previous webhost set up to run `.js` files through the PHP interpreter before serving them.

Comment: Is there an easy fix to it?

Comment: That depends entirely on your webhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick fix might be to modify an existing .htaccess file (or create a new .htaccess file) in the directory that houses your js file.

Try adding one of the following lines to the .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm .js
AddHandler php-script .php .html .htm .js
AddHandler php5-script .php .html .htm .js
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .js
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .js
```

Notice the ".js" at the end? This will instruct the server to process js files through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your previous web host was running .js files through the php interpreter.

The fastest solution would be to include the javascript in the php file within a script tag.

```
...
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var someVar = <?php include 'someJsonFile.geojson'; ?>;
   </script>
</head>
...
```